# iOS Scope Bar Covered Search Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar

Since updating xCode to 6.0.1, the Search Bar has gone wonky and it's hiding the Scope Bar. I don't know if it's because of the update, or if I messed something up unknowingly.

The Scope Bar is showing, but instead of being below the Search Bar, it's now hiding behind the Search Bar, with only a few of the final letters of the Search Bar showing. I've tried playing with the attributes, searching on this site and online and can't find any solutions.

[Here's a screenshot of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzKiuJZV5pTRNDRERVpjSDlGWm8/view?usp=sharing).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

TIA!

Comment: It's a bug in the iOS SDK. I've seen it before. Are you adding the search bar in code or using interface builder?

Comment: Ok, so you need to add the search bar and then *dont change any attributes in IB*. You'll want to configure it entirely in code. If you've changed  anything, delete the search bar and add a new one. Set the outlet then leave it be. Set your scope buttons in code.

Comment: what settings would you recommend for a standard look?

Comment: In code, just add a UISearchBar as the headerView of the table view. Set the scope buttons in code, and you're golden.

Comment: What if I can't set UISearchBar as the table view header? I need the same behaviour, as in Contacts, but with scope bar. And I have this issue in Xcode 6.3.1.